# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'C' was corrupted Ошибка

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Столкнулся с ошибкой:

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'C' was corrupted.

Высвечивается в отладчике и указывает на последнюю функцию, мол с ней что-то не то. Прошу помочь.

Код:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void ini(int arr[5][5]);
void vivid(int arr[5][5]);
void vividpod(int arr[5][5]);



int main() {
    int arr[5][5];
    ini(arr);
    vivid(arr);
    vividpod(arr);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
void ini(int arr[5][5]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }


}
void vivid(int arr[5][5]) {
    for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < 5;j++) {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void vividpod(int arr[5][5])
{
    int pod;
    int C[4];
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pod = arr[4][i];
        C[4] = pod;
        cout << C[4];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так вы же выходите за границы массива - вот стек и повреждается:

```
int C[4];
...
C[4] = pod;
```

Comment: Как можно исправить?

Comment: Вы всерьез? Ну я вам напишу - `C[0] = pod;`. Этой ошибки не будет, но будет ли ваша программа считать то, что вам нужно?

Comment: Большое спасибо